# List of hex string representations need to be XOR-ed

Tags: python, string, hex, xor

I need to XOR through a list of hex values but they are extracted from a text file so they are as strings how can I turn them into hex values?

An example list:

```
['02', '0E', '00', '12', 'D2', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', 
'00', '00', '00', '00', 'CC', '02', '0C', '00', '10', '03', '00', 
'00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '1D', '02', '0A', '00', 
'04', '7E', 'F3', '34', '00', '00', '00', '00', 'B5', '02', '0E', 
'00', '12', 'CF', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00',
'00', '00', 'D1', '02', '0E', '00', '12', 'CC', '00', '00', '00',
'00',  '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', 'D2', '02', '0A', '00',
'04', '7F', 'F3', '34', '00', '00', '00', '00', 'B4', '02', '0A', 
'02', '0E', '00', '12', 'CF', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
```

Comment: Do you by any chance mean bytes instead of hex values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in function [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
>> print(int('0e', 16))
14
```

The second argument tells `int()` to expect numbers in hex, i.e. base 16.

Note that there is no such thing as a "hex value"; hexadecimal is just a notation used when printing the number. `14` and `0xe` are the same number.

You can of course convert the entire list using a list comprehension:

```
list2 = [int(x, 16) for x in list1]
```

Assuming the original list of strings is `list1`.

If you want to print the numbers in hex, use [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex), another built-in:

```
>>> print(hex(int('e', 16)))
0xe
```